# My pandas-generated subplots are layouted incorrectly

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, pandas, drawing, subplot

I ran the following code to get two plots next to each other (it is a minimal working example that you can copy):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pylab import plt

comp1 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=200)
values = pd.Series(comp1)

plt.close("all")
f = plt.figure()
plt.show()

sp1 = f.add_subplot(2,2,1)
values.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.5, color="r", normed=True)

sp2 = f.add_subplot(2,2,2)
values.plot(kind="kde")
```

Unfortunately, I then get the following image:
[image]

**This is also an interesting layout, but I wanted the figures to be next to each other. What did I do wrong? How can I correct it?**

For clarity, I could also use this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pylab import plt

comp1 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=200)
values = pd.Series(comp1)

plt.close("all")
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
plt.show()
axes[0,0].hist(values, bins=100, alpha=0.5, color="r", normed=True) # Until here, it works. You get a half-finished correct image of what I was going for (though it is 2x2 here)
axes[0,1].plot(values, kind="kde") # This does not work
```

Unfortunately, in this approach `axes[0,1]` refers to the subplot that has a `plot` method but does not know `kind="kde"`. Please take into consideration that the in the first version `plot` is executed on the pandas object, whereas in the second version `plot` is executed on the subplot, which does not work with the `kind="kde"` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ax=` argument to set which subplot object to plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pylab import plt

comp1 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=200)
values = pd.Series(comp1)

plt.close("all")
f = plt.figure()
sp1 = f.add_subplot(2,2,1)
values.hist(bins=100, alpha=0.5, color="r", normed=True, ax=sp1)

sp2 = f.add_subplot(2,2,2)
values.plot(kind="kde", ax=sp2)
```

[image]